# what is the earpods controls technically doing?

Tags: iphone, ear-phones

I try to implement the same functions from earspods control middle button with an regular button, for an device which use the same functions and connection.

Normally when you push the button ones you can pause, two times change the song etc. But does the button have an internal logic, or does it cut off a connecting (ground/mic/LR) for the time it is pushed?

Comment: Does https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-does-iphone-headphone-remote-circuit-work.841431/ help?

Comment: Yes that is the solution! Thank you!